# pass different local variable to click event

Tags: c#, webforms

I want to pass ID value inside to btn_click event.  here I am getting ID value dynamically after running some code inside RunStoreProcedure. how can declare globally after getting ID value from RunStoreProcedure.?

```
public void RunStoreProcedure()
    {
    string ID = "123456";// 
    }


    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {           

                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ ID +".doc");
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `string ID = "";` as a **global variable**, outside the function.

And your `RunStoreProcedure` should be something like this :

```
public void RunStoreProcedure()
{
    //your logic here. 
    ID = result.ToString();
}
```

Hence your `ID` variable will have the value coming from the stored procedure or whichever way you want it to be and that can now be passed in the `btn_Click` event.

Hope this clears the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it from different functions including different id's then do this.

```
public static string id="";

public void RunStoreProcedure()
{
    string ID = "123456";
    id=ID;
}


protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+ id +".doc");
         }
```